# Cannot schedule backup on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I try to [schedule a backup on Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups) but got an error:

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '15:30 Asia/Tokyo'
```

got

```
▸    Invalid schedule format: expected --at '[HOUR]:00 [TIMEZONE]'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, can only schedule on the hour:

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '16:00 Asia/Tokyo'
```

will schedule at 4 pm in Tokyo.